# How do I navigate to another page from another c# class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

I have a main page which has a play, options and exit button, both the play and exit button work as I followed a tutorial on it however for the options button I do not know how to navigate it. What I am planning to do is to create another class called optionsMenu.cs and have like a credits screen or a how to play guide on it. 
These are the codes that I have for my options button.

```
var optionsGameButton = new Button(buttonTexture, buttonFont)
        {
            Position = new Vector2(300, 250),
            Text = "Options",
        };

        optionsGameButton.Click += OptionsGameButton_Click;

_components = new List<Component>()
        {
            titleGameButton,
            playGameButton,
            optionsGameButton,
            exitGameButton,
        };
```

Finally I know I have to write a code in this area to be able to get the options button working but I don't know which kind of code to put.

```
private void OptionsGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Credits");
    }
```

Comment: I do believe you have mis-labeled this code with monogame/ xna.  The button class does not exist in either XNA nor MonoGame. While it is possible to use events and handlers in XNA/MonoGame, it is not common to do so.(Inconsistent timing).  It is possible to use a forms wrapper for a MonoGame game object, even then all state changes must be atomic.  There is just too much left out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using click events, then you'll need to create a new instance of your options page and set it as the content of your control object within OptionsGameButton_Click.  On the options page you'll need to set the xmlns to your optionsMenu.cs file.

I think you could also set the content of your control object by passing it as a parameter within the method itself, but I've only done this using the ICommand interface.